# How to call custom 503 page without error message in developer mode?

Tags: magento2, error, theme, magento-2.1.8, maintenance

I have create custom error template into pub\errors\custom folder and Customize 503.phtml template file and write custom message into it.

In Site Default Mode and Production Mode Template File Working Well **except developer mode**.

So, can anyone tell me how to call my custom template file message in developer mode.

Thanks in advance...!

Answer (score 0):

The decision to show a 503 page is done in `\Magento\Framework\App\Http::catchException`, specifically in method `handleBootstrapErrors`.

```
public function catchException(Bootstrap $bootstrap, \Exception $exception)
    {
        $result = $this->handleDeveloperMode($bootstrap, $exception)
            || $this->handleBootstrapErrors($bootstrap, $exception)
            || $this->handleSessionException($exception)
            || $this->handleInitException($exception)
            || $this->handleGenericReport($bootstrap, $exception);
        return $result;
    }
```

But if developer mode is enabled then `handleDeveloperMode` returs true so the others don't get executed.

If you just need to work on / design the 503 page then you can just add `return false;` at the beginning of `handleDeveloperMode`